# Configure Eclipse to prefer system library imports?

Tags: java, eclipse

The Eclipse import function (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>) is very time-saving but when multiple classes with the same name are available and I want to import a class of the system libraries (e.g. `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`) I often get the wrong one. Is it possible to always rank the classes whose package starts with `java.` at the top?

Comment: You can disable classes/packages you know you are not going to use in `Build Path` -> `Configure Build Path...` -> `Access Rules`. I usually have `java/awt/**` there to avoid confusing `java.awt.List` with `java.util.List`.

Comment: @Banthar That helped in the List case but e.g. the type "Function" has so many implementations that I can't all exclude.